# How can git bisect tell me which merge broke the master branch?

Tags: git, bisect

Git bisect is branch aware, so it will usually happily venture into some branch to test those commits. I am not interested in whether the branch contains some bad commits. I am interested in whether or not merging a feature broke something, essentially the same as if I had squashed the entire branch into a single commit.

Is there a way I can instruct git bisect to stay on a given branch (right side, left side) so that I can figure this out?

The obstacle that I see is which branch to follow if going backwards, but there might be some way of handling that perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

That would be : `git bisect --first-parent`

---

The closest thing to "the commits of a given branch" in git is to take the sequence of leftmost commits from the head of that branch, and several commands (`git log`, `git show` and `git bisect` among others) accept a `--first-parent` option to represent that.